# How can I get the mediaelement.js to work in a popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, mp3, mediaelement.js

I got the Media Element JS player to work, but when I tried to get it to play in a pop-up, I noticed that it breaks the popup. It looks like I can't call JavaScript inside a JavaScript.  My popup is pretty simple, it just does window.open and uses document.write with code to build a new page with its own style sheet. However, I can't load the mediaelement.js stuff inside that. Maybe I should just load the Flash that comes with it? There's also a silverlight file.

Can someone please help? I need a player that doesn't require an XML file for the playlist, works in all browsers, plays MP3s and has a timer on it. I've been working on it all day to no avail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're document.writing into a new window you should be able to write a  call to an external js file and that should run. Can you post the code you're using?

also why not just window.open('http://yoursite.com/path/to/an/html/file.html') instead of document.writing to it. This would be cleaner and would maintain the separation of structure and behavior.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer! I didn't know I could open another file like that. However, since this is working with WordPress, I don't know if I can still get the MP3 URL I need since that's in the loop.

Comment: Okay, I got a test page running the media player in a popup just fine now! However, I wonder if I can write to the page in the popup from the page that triggers the popup. Is this possible?